# how to run a bash script (with parameters) in gitlab ci?

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab, cicd

I have a scripts repo, which have few scripts among which I have a build.sh file that I want to run when GitLab CI runs. Can I simply add that to my GitLab CI file under scripts section? Which I am assuming it will run the script file.

Is there a way I can add and pass variables from my GitLab CI file/environment to the hello.sh file?

My project:

```
rootdir
  - folder1
  - scripts
      - hello.sh
```

`hello.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello World!"
```

GitLab CI:

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./scripts/hello.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign values to your variables in the CI/CD settings (see screenshot below). Then you can use those variables in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  
variables:
  SMTP_USERNAME: ${SMTP_USERNAME}
  SMTP_PASSWORD: ${SMTP_PASSWORD}

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./email.sh
```

I prefer this approach because it means that the environment variable values are not hard-coded into a file and are easy changed via the GitLab UI.

[image]

Comment: thanks . i have minor follow up question. so in the script section, is it any linux commands , i can add/run?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Provided that the command is available in the `docker` base image. If not then you need to install it or change the base image. 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are possible. To use your `hello.sh` script in GitLab CI and pass variables directly from your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, just define your variables under the `variables` section(*below I included a **GREETING** variable as an example*). Then, when you run your script, those variables will automatically be available to it.

First make sure your `hello.sh` script is executable. You can achieve that by running `chmod +x ./scripts/hello.sh` locally, in the root of your repo. Or you can also have this as the first command to run under your Gitlab CI file’s script section, before running your script.

Then modify your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to include the variables and run your script like this:

```yaml
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  
variables:
  GREETING: "Welcome to GitLab CI/CD!"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./scripts/hello.sh
```

For your question on whether you can access the variable in your `hello.sh`, you can access the `GREETING` variable using `$GREETING`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello World! $GREETING"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing your **variables** (for ex: VARIABLE_AAA, VARIABLE_BBB) as **arguments** to the `Bash` script:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: docker:latest

stages:
 - build

build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - chmod +x ./scripts/hello.sh
  - ./scripts/hello.sh "VARIABLE_AAA" "VARIABLE_BBBB"
```

`hello.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
VAR_A=$1
VAR_B=$2
echo $VAR_A
echo $VAR_B
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wjQa.png)

More details in: [arguments in bash script](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/use-command-line-arguments-in-bash-script)